# Datamatrix JavaScript Scanner

Tags: javascript, jquery, datamatrix

Looking for a simple way to scan a data matrix from a picture, or even better: from a live video.

I have tried this https://github.com/zxing-js/library
I just copied their example for UMD and I get an error because of the 'await'.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the error? You sure you are using a modern browser and not IE11?

Comment: @ppumkin it was in chrome, something about that it could only be used in async functions

Comment: are you sure you imported that UMD library thing in the correct place and then tried to do your code AFTER page loaded.. becuase it may be trying to run before the UMD thing loads

Comment: @ppumkin did I miss something? I thought I just just copy the code on the github and use it. Do I need extra files?